# Why is my model undefined?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

Have some trouble with my model. When I go to save the status, I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

Anyone have any ideas? I'm super new to Backbone and even newer to Coffeescript.

```
View = require 'views/base/view'
module.exports= class TaskView extends View
  autoRender: true
  eventSounder:false
  taskRemoveTimeout:500

  completeTask:(e)=>
    e.preventDefault() if e
    e.stopPropagation() if e
    @toggleStatus()
    @model.save {
      status: @model.get('status') # error
    }, {
      success: =>
        unless @removeTaskTimeout
          @removeTaskTimeout = setTimeout(@removeTaskItem, @taskRemoveTimeout)
    }

  toggleStatus: =>
    if @model.get('status') is 'OPEN'
      if @removeTaskTimeout
        clearTimeout @removeTaskTimeout
        @removeTaskTimeout = null
      @model.set('status', 'CLOSED')
    else if @model.get('status') is 'CLOSED'
      @model.set('status', 'OPEN')

  removeTaskItem: =>
    if @model.get('status') is 'CLOSED'
      @eventSounder = true
      @datastore.userTasks.remove @model
      @model?.collection?.remove @model
      console.log @model

  getTemplateData: =>
    td = super
    td.completeClass = "complete" if @model.isComplete?()
    td.assignedBy = @datastore.dimensionUsers.getUserName(@model.get('assigner'))
    if !td.assignedBy
      td.assignedBy = "Dimension User Not Found"
    td
```

Update:

Here's the view with the event that calls completeTask:

```
View = require 'views/base/task'
template = require 'views/templates/fanview/right/task_carousel_item'

module.exports = class TaskCarouselItem extends View
  template: template
  template = null
  className: 'item'

  listen:
    'change model' : 'render'
    'toggleStatus model' : 'completeTask'

  attach: ->
    super
    id = @model.id
    @$el.data('id', id)
    @publishEvent 'taskCarousel:status:update'

  initialize: ->
    super
    console.log 'Initialize', @model
```

Comment: If you need any more information, let me know. I have no idea what I'm doing :).

Comment: @tieTYT - It's this line here: status: @model.get('status') # error

Comment: @muistooshort - I added where I think completeTask is being called, the toggleStatus model event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with coffeescript syntax, but it looks like your `@model.get('status')` is not using the right `this`. To fix that, try using the following (but convert this to coffeescript):

```
// Before @model.save
var status = this.model.get('status');
this.model.save ({
  status: status
});
```

Comment: Do you need parenthesis after the model.save? Or, are you passing in a model to your view?

Comment: It fails to compile if I do that, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Believe we found the issue.

When toggleStatus changes the status or whatever, there maybe is a listener elsewhere on the model. When the model changes (specifically status), it gets destroyed. So when completeTask continues, the model has been destroyed at that point.

Thanks for all the help, everyone :).